# Generic way to create different pojo objects and persist in db

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pojo

I'm creating a project that uses spring data jpa for persistance. I'm receiving a json string as input that I transform to the corresponding pojo to save into the db. Currently I'm using if else to determine the pojo and the corresponding repository. Is there a way to handle this generically instead of using if else.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

here is my code:

```
                    if(designation.equals("Teacher"))
                    {
                        Teacher teacher= mapper.readValue(jsonString,Teacher.class);
                        teacherRepository.save(teacher);
                    }
                    else  if(designation.equals("Student"))
                    {
                        Student student= mapper.readValue(jsonString,Student.class);
                        studentRepository.save(student);
                    }
                    else  if(designation.equals("Staff"))
                    {
                        Staff staff= mapper.readValue(jsonString,Staff.class);
                        staffRepository.save(staff);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have resources which use different repositories maybe you should have different REST endpoints (or whatever you are using) and service classes right.

One simple way to get rid of your if-else blocks would be to use a Map

```
Map<String, Consumer<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put("Teacher", (e) -> teacherRepository.save(mapper.readValue(e,Teacher.class))
});
```

and you can use it like,

```
map.get("Teacher").accept(jsonString);
```